# Visible Name Tag on Invisible Mobs Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there any way to summon an invisible mob with a completely visible name tag? The data tag {Invisible:1} doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

`Invisible:1` only works for armor stands. For other mobs, you will need to given them the invisibility potion effect:

```
ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Amplifier:0,Duration:2147483647,ShowParticles:0b}]
```

---

The invisibility effect, however, seems to hide name tags. To get around this, you could use an entity that is already invisible (area effect cloud) riding the main entity, and put the name on that instead:

```
Passengers:[{id:area_effect_cloud,CustomName:"Aria",CustomNameVisible:1,Duration:2147483647}]
```

---

The full command would look something like:

**1.11+**

```
/summon pig ~ ~1 ~ {ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Amplifier:0,Duration:2147483647,ShowParticles:0b}],Passengers:[{id:area_effect_cloud,CustomName:"Oink",CustomNameVisible:1,Duration:2147483647}]}
```

**1.10-**

```
/summon Pig ~ ~1 ~ {ActiveEffects:[{Id:14,Amplifier:0,Duration:2147483647,ShowParticles:0b}],Passengers:[{id:AreaEffectCloud,CustomName:"Oink",CustomNameVisible:1,Duration:2147483647}]}
```

[image: Invisible pig (not pictured)]

---

If the entity type doesn't matter (e.g: you only want to create invisible floating text), then you can use an area effect cloud or armor stand on its own:

**Armor stand:**

```
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {Marker:1b,Invisible:1b,CustomName:"Stanley",CustomNameVisible:1b}
```

**Area effect cloud:**

```
/summon AreaEffectCloud ~ ~ ~ {Duration:2147483647,CustomName:"Aria",CustomNameVisible:1b}
```

(Switch `ArmorStand`/`AreaEffectCloud` with `armor_stand`/`area_effect_cloud` if you're using **1.11+**.)

Comment: Ok sorry, I forgot that only armor stands use the Invisible tag. I haven't tried putting an invisible entity on another one, but it might work. I'm just trying to summon an invisible villager with a name tag, all for making a device detect when I right-click it. Thanks.